# TextField onChange как?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, reactjs, material-ui

Была у меня форма, решил её заменить на компоненты MaterialUi

В обычной форме у меня были инпуты с **onChange**
который передавал состояние,вопрос как реализовать это в **TextField**

```
<form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
    <input type={"email"} onChange={(e)=>this.setState({...this.state, email: e.target.value})}/>
    <input type={"password"} onChange={(e)=>this.setState({...this.state, password: e.target.value})}/>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Компонент с MaterialUi**

```
const SignInComponent = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    const signIn = useSignIn()
    const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState({username: '', password: ''})

    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        axios.post('https://elepsio.herokuapp.com/auth/login', formData)
            .then((res)=>{
                if(res.status === 200){
                    if(signIn({token: res.data.token, 
                            expiresIn:res.data.expiresIn,
                            tokenType: "Bearer",
                            authState: res.data.authUserState})){
                        // Redirect or do-something
                    }else {
                        console.log("Error")
                    }
                }
            })
    }

    return (
<Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
    <CssBaseline />
    <div className={classes.paper}>

    <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
      <LockOutlinedIcon />
    </Avatar>

    <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
      Войти в систему
    </Typography>

    <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <TextField
        variant="outlined"
        margin="normal"
        required
        fullWidth
        id="username"
        label="Имя"
        name="username"
        autoComplete="username"
        autoFocus
   
      />
      <TextField
        
        variant="outlined"
        margin="normal"
        required
        fullWidth
        name="password"
        label="Password"
        type="password"
        id="password"
        autoComplete="current-password"

      />

      <Button
        type="submit"
        fullWidth
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        className={classes.submit}
      >
        Войти
      </Button>

    </form>
  </div>

</Container>
    )
}

export default SignInComponent;
```

Comment: на `<TextField />` добавить `onChange={e => myFunction(e)}`

Comment: у меня два филда с двумя полями

Comment: заведите состояние для каждого поля и считывайте значение

Answer (score 0):

```
   <TextField
                    onChange = {(e)=>setFormData({...formData, password: e.target.value})}
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    required
                    fullWidth
                    name="password"
                    label="Пароль"
                    type="password"
                    id="password"
                    autoComplete="current-password"

                />
```